# Simple code for FTP Server in python

Tags: python, ftp-server

I want to built a simple FTP server in python which will serve the client in just downloading a text file. Can any one kindly help me by suggesting the best study material to refer and help me finding some code snippets.

Comment: Must it be FTP? HTTP would be much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the FTP examples with twisted

- http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/#auto8

Also a simple implementation: ftpdrop.py

- http://www.mythi.cx/python/

Comment: Thanks again...The whole day i was doing google for FTP sample code,but i wasn't successful.... U made my work simpler...Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 4):

I can recommend [pyftpdlib hosted at Github](https://github.com/giampaolo/pyftpdlib)

Example:

```
>>> from pyftpdlib.authorizers import DummyAuthorizer
>>> from pyftpdlib.handlers import FTPHandler
>>> from pyftpdlib.servers import FTPServer
>>>
>>> authorizer = DummyAuthorizer()
>>> authorizer.add_user("user", "12345", "/home/giampaolo", perm="elradfmw")
>>> authorizer.add_anonymous("/home/nobody")
>>>
>>> handler = FTPHandler
>>> handler.authorizer = authorizer
>>>
>>> server = FTPServer(("127.0.0.1", 21), handler)
>>> server.serve_forever()
[I 13-02-19 10:55:42] >>> starting FTP server on 127.0.0.1:21 <<<
[I 13-02-19 10:55:42] poller: <class 'pyftpdlib.ioloop.Epoll'>
[I 13-02-19 10:55:42] masquerade (NAT) address: None
[I 13-02-19 10:55:42] passive ports: None
[I 13-02-19 10:55:42] use sendfile(2): True
[I 13-02-19 10:55:45] 127.0.0.1:34178-[] FTP session opened (connect)
[I 13-02-19 10:55:48] 127.0.0.1:34178-[user] USER 'user' logged in.
[I 13-02-19 10:56:27] 127.0.0.1:34179-[user] RETR /home/giampaolo/.vimrc completed=1 bytes=1700 seconds=0.001
[I 13-02-19 10:56:39] 127.0.0.1:34179-[user] FTP session closed (disconnect).
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://cr.yp.to/ftp.html) is probably the best you can find to understand the FTP protocol. Implementation should be pretty simple once you've understood the mechanism.

Comment: I have gone through the details of ftp protocol, but the implementation using it is bit different. I want a simple sample code to get some idea of it.

Comment: @Nilesh Nar: Provided an example with twisted.